# How to set String Value to ExpandableListView Childs text on click?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, expandablelistview

Got a nice explanation and this may prove useful to anyone trying to do the same!!!

```
   public class ExpList extends ExpandableListActivity
{
 String gametype;

  // strings for group elements

    static final String arrGroupelements[] = 
    {
   "POKER TOURNAMENTS",
   "SLOTS TOURNAMENTS",
   "ROULLETTE/CRAPS TOURNAMENTS",
   "BLACKJACK TOURNAMENTS",
   "BINGO/CHARITY BINGO"
 };


  // strings for child elements

 static final String arrChildelements[][] = 
 {
   {
  "TEXAS HOLD'EM",
  "OMAHA HIGH-LOW",
  "SEVEN CARD STUD",
  "THREE CARD POKER",
  "OTHER POKER VARIANTS",
  "ONLINE/SATTELITE TOURNAMENTS"
   },
   {
  "SLOTS"
   },
   {
  "ROULLETTE",
  "CRAPS"

   },
   {
  "BLACKJACK"
   },
   {
       "BINGO"
        }
    };
```

AND working onChildClick function as follows to set value of string to "TEXAS HOLD 'EM" when that child is clicked below

```
@Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            //ExpandableListAdapter adapter = getExpandableListAdapter();
            gametype = ExpList.arrChildelements[groupPosition][childPosition];
            //---------------------
            Intent pullt = new Intent(ExpList.this,
                    SearchActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("gametype", gametype);
            pullt.putExtras(bundle);
            pullt.putExtra("gametype", gametype);

            startActivity(pullt);
            //---------------------
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: What does your `ExpAdapter` do?

Comment: Nothing, Yet.  My objective is lets say TEXAS HOLD EM is clicked. Then  the value of gametype needs to set value to "Texas Hold Em" to be passed to parsing activity. Like so See edit at bottom of description

Answer (score 0):

In `onChildClick()` you get `groupPosition` and `childPosition`.

```
ExpandableListAdapter adapter = getExpandableListAdapter();
gametype = adapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString;
```

Comment: So would I paste that code inside of the onChildClick event? Like ExpandableListAdapter adapter = getExpandableListAdapter();

Comment: Getting a null pointer exception. See edit at bottom of description. This is what I've got in the onchildclick event.

Comment: Got a nice explanation and rundown on how to do this. See Edited description for future reference

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ExpList extends ExpandableListActivity
{
 String gametype;

  // strings for group elements

    static final String arrGroupelements[] = 
    {
   "POKER TOURNAMENTS",
   "SLOTS TOURNAMENTS",
   "ROULLETTE/CRAPS TOURNAMENTS",
   "BLACKJACK TOURNAMENTS",
   "BINGO/CHARITY BINGO"
 };


  // strings for child elements

 static final String arrChildelements[][] = 
 {
   {
  "TEXAS HOLD'EM",
  "OMAHA HIGH-LOW",
  "SEVEN CARD STUD",
  "THREE CARD POKER",
  "OTHER POKER VARIANTS",
  "ONLINE/SATTELITE TOURNAMENTS"
   },
   {
  "SLOTS"
   },
   {
  "ROULLETTE",
  "CRAPS"

   },
   {
  "BLACKJACK"
   },
   {
       "BINGO"
        }
    };
```

AND working onChildClick function as follows to set value of string to "TEXAS HOLD 'EM" when that child is clicked below

```
@Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            //ExpandableListAdapter adapter = getExpandableListAdapter();
            gametype = ExpList.arrChildelements[groupPosition][childPosition];
            //---------------------
            Intent pullt = new Intent(ExpList.this,
                    SearchActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("gametype", gametype);
            pullt.putExtras(bundle);
            pullt.putExtra("gametype", gametype);

            startActivity(pullt);
            //---------------------
            return false;
        }
```